# Problems streaming arrow to DuckDB wasm

Tags: google-bigquery, pyarrow, apache-arrow, duckdb, google-bigquery-storage-api

***Apologies in advance for the wall of text***

I am working on a PoC to see whether we can expose data from our Data warehouse in an relatively effective effective way out to a browser client.

**Data warehouse**: Bigquery

**API**: Bigquery storage read api

One of approaches that I'm trying to get working is utilizing BigQuery's Storage Read API that allows us to open a stream (in a Arrow IPC RecordBatch format).

Currently I have tried to create a simple Python API that invokes the BigQuery Storage Read API to then stream the response back to the client (i.e. browser client running DuckDB wasm).

*Note: I've made some smaller tests and I can see that the stream from the Bigquery Storage API only contains the schema as part of the first message. Which I understand aligns to the arrow streaming format.*

DuckDB Wasm - according to the docs is capable of loading data from an [arrow IPC stream](https://shell.duckdb.org/docs/classes/index.DuckDBConnection.html#insertArrowFromIPCStream) so that's what I am looking to use.

However I am currently getting this error in the client when making the request to the python (streaming) api.

```
async_bindings.ts:150 Uncaught Error: Expected IPC message of type schema but got record batch
```

**But I don't quite understand what I am doing wrong here, any help would be appreciated?**

#### Python API

##### bq_storage_reader.py

```
def bq_storage_reader(
    client: BigQueryReadClient,
    source_model: BQStorageQuery,
    streams: int = 1
) -> tuple[ReadSession, list[ReadRowsStream]]:

    table = source_model.source.table
    dataset = source_model.source.dataset
    project = source_model.source.project

    read_session = types.ReadSession()
    read_session.table = BIGQUERY_TABLE_TEMPLATE.format(
        project, dataset, table)
    read_session.data_format = types.DataFormat.ARROW

    read_session.read_options.selected_fields = source_model.fields
    read_session.read_options.row_restriction = 'AND '.join(
        source_model.record_filters)

    session = client.create_read_session(
        parent=PARENT_PROJECT.format(project),
        read_session=read_session,
        max_stream_count=streams,
    )

    # message_reader = pa.ipc.open_stream(session.arrow_schema.serialized_schema)
    # schema = message_reader.schema

    readers = [client.read_rows(stream.name) for stream in session.streams]

    return session, readers
```

##### get_record_batches_async.py

```
async def get_record_batches_async(session: ReadSession, stream: ReadRowsStream):
    # only first message from the Iterable[stream] has the schema
    for record_batch in stream:
        yield record_batch.arrow_record_batch.serialized_record_batch
```

##### main.py

```
client = bigquery_storage_v1.BigQueryReadClient()
    
router = APIRouter()

@router.get('/stores/{store_id}/stream', tags=["pos"])
async def get_stream(
        store_id: str,
        from_date: str = None,
        to_date: str = None):

    logger.info({'store': store_id, 'from': from_date, 'to': to_date})

    bsq = BQStorageQuery(
        fields=None,
        record_filters=[f"store_identifier in ('{store_id}')",
                        f"d_date_sale between '{from_date}' AND '{to_date}'"],
        source=BaseSource(
            table='<tablename>',
            dataset='<dataset>',
            project='<gcp-project>',
            partition_cols=['<partition_col>']
        )
    )

    session, streams = bq_storage_reader(client, bsq)

    if streams is None or len(streams) == 0:
        raise HTTPException(status_code=404, detail="data not found")

    return StreamingResponse(
        get_record_batches_async(session=session, stream=streams[0])
    )
```

#### Client (duckdb wasm)

```js
const bundle = await duckdb.selectBundle(MANUAL_BUNDLES);

// Instantiate the asynchronus version of DuckDB-wasm
const worker = new Worker(bundle.mainWorker);
const logger = new duckdb.ConsoleLogger();
const db = new duckdb.AsyncDuckDB(logger, worker);
await db.instantiate(bundle.mainModule, bundle.pthreadWorker);

const conn = await db.connect(); // Connect to db

const queryParams = {
  from_date: "2022-04-08",
  to_date: "2022-07-08",
};

const url =
  "http://localhost:8081/stores/1003446/stream?from_date=2022-04-08&to_date=2022-07-08";

const streamResponse = await fetch(url);
const streamReader = streamResponse.body.getReader();
const streamInserts = [];
let createTable = true;
while (true) {
  const { value, done } = await streamReader.read();
  if (done) break;
  streamInserts.push(
    conn.insertArrowFromIPCStream(value, {
      name: "streamed",
      create: createTable,
    })
  );
  if (createTable) {
    createTable = false;
  }
}
console.log(streamInserts.length);
await Promise.all(streamInserts);

// Basic query
console.log("Basic query");
let q = await conn.query(`select count(*)::integer as cnt from streamed`); // Returns v = 101
console.log("Query result (Arrow Table):", q);
```

Comment: Hi! Looks like a very intersting use case. I am probably best placed to answer (working @duckdb on duckdb-wasm), but will take a bit longer to go through the question. Thanks for providing lots of details, make my life easier!
(Also, you are welcome also to join at https://discord.duckdb.org where others might want to chip in / share their experiences)

Comment: Awesome @CarloPiovesan! Yeah no worries, always happy to share more details if needed. In parallel I am trying to validate whether the stream created is actually correct or not which might explain the error I am seeing

Good shout about the discord - will make sure to join!

Comment: @me_L_coding did you make any progress on this? Do you have additional code samples you can share on this PoC?

Comment: @Dude0001 sure, let me see if I can share a gist (or something a bit more digistable). In addition to above I wrote a small node.js app just to double-check whether there was something related to duckdb wasm or just the data in general. That seemed to work at least...so right now I am thinking there is something wrong on the DuckDB wasm end...potentially

Will share when I'm home

Comment: @Dude0001 https://gist.github.com/Jeyob/94d0565e3b9b02dc3ab9311b75abc36e

Performancewise not great though ~30s for 260k rows

Comment: @me_L_coding In your gist you have `return StreamingResponse(
        get_record_batches_async(session=session, stream=streams[0]),
        media_type='application/octet-stream'
    )` surely that shouldn't be streams[0], right?

Comment: no thats correct @DeanMacGregor that was just me fixating one stream when testing, in practice you would want to have something more robust...